# VBA: "Too few parameters; Expected 1; "

Tags: ms-access, insert, vba

I have a form in access. I'm using VBA to enter the values into the table.

**Problem:**

`"Too few parameters; Expected 1;"` - I'm getting this error EVEN THOUGH THE TABLE COLUMN NAMES MATCHES WHAT IS IN THE INSERT STATEMENT.

```
Private Sub Command125_Click()
    Dim dbsCurrent As Database
    Set dbsCurrent = CurrentDb

    'add data to table production_date, reason, downtime_minutes, comment , Me.Text126, Me.Text121, Me.Text123, Me.Text128
    dbsCurrent.Execute " INSERT INTO tbl_Downtime " _
    & "(job) VALUES " _
    & "(dbsCurrent.Me.Text116);"

End Sub
```

**End Goal:**

First of all I want to fix this error. But I also need to be able to update the row based on the ID (auto-numbered in the table). How do I allow users to update the row if they know the ID of the row?

Comment: Please do yourself a favor and rename your controls like `Command125` and `Text116` to **meaningful** names. This really helps the readability of your code.

Comment: I literally realized that after going through the headache of this question haha thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that you put quotation marks around your VBA reference to Text116. I assume "job" is a string. Try the following:

```
Private Sub Command125_Click()
Dim dbsCurrent As Database
Set dbsCurrent = CurrentDb

'add data to table production_date, reason, downtime_minutes, comment , Me.Text126, Me.Text121, Me.Text123, Me.Text128
dbsCurrent.Execute " INSERT INTO tbl_Downtime " _
& "('job') VALUES " _
& "('" & dbsCurrent.Text116 & "');"

End Sub
```

Comment: Try it with `Me.Text116.Value` instead of `dbsCurrent.Me.Text116`

Comment: That value probably requires escaping.

Comment: Nice catch @HansUp, though now that I think of it, I don't think the `me.` is needed.

Comment: Did your attempt include `('job') VALUES`?  Don't quote the target field name:  `([job]) VALUES`

Comment: I copy pasted the code above and I get an error: `Compile error: Method or data member not found`.

Comment: The debugger is highlighting `.Text116`

Comment: @HansUp even after removing the single quotes from `job` I still get the same error highlighting the same `.Text116`

Comment: If `Text116` is the name of a text box on your form, see my first comment.  At least that should not trigger a compile error.

Comment: Got it - I just had to switch to `Me.Text116` instead of including the `dbsCurrent` prefix.

Comment: What would the code look like for updating? (the second part to my question)